# How to get all items related to a Foreign Key in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

My aim is to get all the items with a particular category from the model I created. For example, if I should get a category with an ID, I want to get all the products that is in that category.

Below is my model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

```
class Category(models.Model):
    #product = models.ForeignKey('Product', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Below is my view

```
def getCategory(request, pk):
    category = Category.objects.get(id=pk)
    # product = Product.objects.all()
    products = Product.category_set.all()
    # Product.category_set.all()
    context = {'category': category, 'products':products}
    return render(request, '*.html', context)
```

I tried using Product.category_set.all() and I have tried to flip it over, getting the products relaed to the category that I got the ID but I dont know how I can do that.

I used this loop below in my template and it worked but I wonder if there is a better way to do it.

Template

{% for product in products %}

{% if product.category.id == category.id %}

```
View
def getCategory(request, pk):
    category = Category.objects.get(id=pk)
    products = Product.objects.all()
    context = {'category': category, 'products':products}
    return render(request, 'products/shop.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the field (category) of the secondary model (Product) associated with the primary model to select with the identifier of [the primary model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) (Category). To do this, specify this field and, through a double underscore, the desired field of the primary model.

```
Product.objects.filter(category__id=pk)
```

Comment: @Ayatoo if the answer helped. You can count it by checking the box below the top and bottom triangle.